# getting values from jtable after disabling the editing option

Tags: java, swing, jtable, netbeans-8

cant call methods like `System.out.println(sellTable.getValueAt(sellTable.getSelectedRow(),1));`
in `mouse click` event 
after disabling the `jtable` editing option , how to get values from selected column and row just by clicking on them after disabling the editing option

Comment: `cant call methods like...` - sure you can. The isCellEditable(...) method has no effect on the `getValueAt(...)` method.

Comment: How did you disabled the editing option?
Did you unchecked enabled from the properties?

Comment: yeah i unchecked the enable option after that getselectedraw() is not working mouseevents are working

Answer (score 0):

you can use this method :

```
   public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex);
```

from your table class (implements public interface `TableModel`)

Can you provide some code to reproduce the problem?

Comment: if i provide Table.getSelectedRow()  as the rowindex code isnot working

Comment: 'private void tableMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt){
String s = details.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(),2).toString());
}'